# unable to send array as parameter using python suds

Tags: python-2.7, suds

I'm trying to connect to a web service using python suds , the target web service method has the below output :

```
 enqueue(xs:string username, xs:string password, xs:string domain, xs:int msgType, ArrayOf_xsd_string messages, ArrayOf_xsd_string destinations, ArrayOf_xsd_string originators, ArrayOf_xsd_string udhs, ArrayOf_xsd_string mClass, )
```

for example parameter destinations expect array of string to pass but I don't have any idea how should i pass an array to the service using python list

here is my code :

```
    import suds
from suds import * 
from array import *
from string import *

url = "http://somewhere?wsdl"
client = suds.client.Client(url)
#print client 

message = {'test'}



try :
     result = client.service.enqueue("xxx" , "xxx" , "xxx" ,0 , message ,number, orginator , None , None)
except WebFault, e:
    print e
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?